# Virtual keyboard conflicts with Nimbus

Tags: java, action, nimbus, virtual-keyboard

I was wondering why [Nimbus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) would be conflicting somehow with [Virtual keys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html). Check out the sample I made below:

```
    public class buttontest implements ActionListener {

    JMenuItem close =new JMenuItem("Close");

    public static void main (String[] args){

    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // handle exception
    }

    }

    public buttontest(){

    JFrame test = new JFrame();
    JMenuBar bar=new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file=new JMenu("File");

    close.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

    test.setExtendedState(test.getExtendedState() | test.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // Maximized Window or setSize(getMaximumSize())
    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);

    bar.add(file);
    file.add(close);
    test.setJMenuBar(bar);
    test.setVisible(true);  
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if(e.getSource()==close){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

The way its wrote, you can try to use the Virtual keys. You will see that Alt F works to open the File menu but Alt C doesnt close the application. In other way, if you comment the Nimbus code both virtual Keys will work.

I made one research regarding to this "bug" (or maybe something wrong Im doing that Im not aware) but until now I found nothing. Has someone ever passed through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `setAccelerator()` method for `JMenuItem`:

```
close.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.ALT_MASK ));
```

From Javadoc:
`JMenuItem#setAccelerator(KeyStroke)`

> Sets the key combination which
>   invokes the menu item's action listeners without navigating the menu
>   hierarchy. It is the UI's responsibility to install the correct
>   action. Note that when the keyboard accelerator is typed, it will work
>   whether or not the menu is currently displayed.

---

**Additional note:**

1. Replace `LookAndFeelInfo` to `UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo` as it's an *inner* class inside `UIManager`.
2. Call the constructor in the *main* method.
3. Change the parameter of `setDefaultCloseOperation(1)` to 3 as `3 = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, but `1=JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE` which hides the frame, personally, I hate it, because close button created for **closing** frame, **not** hiding it, like Skype.
4. Add *actionListener* to *close* button :`close.addActionListener(this);`

Comment: one word for you dude: GENIUS!